# Do I need to keep those variables global?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xtermjs

Once I reached out of scopes, from events, I need to keep referencing variables that was declared in the parent scope. In below code, `fitAddon`. In order to prevent JS's GC to clean up my variable, do I need to keep it global like below? this isn't much clear to me.

```
// do I need to keep this to use in handleResize() event or
// it would be fine if it was local, i.e., same scope as
// it was initialized?
 let fitAddon: FitAddon;

export const Terminal = () => {

  const id = 'xterm-container';
  useEffect(() => {
    const terminal = new TerminalType({
      cursorBlink: true,
      cursorStyle: window.api.isWindows ? "bar" : "underline",
      cols: DefaultTerminalSize.cols,
      rows: DefaultTerminalSize.rows,
    });

    fitAddon = new FitAddon();
    terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
    
    terminal.open(document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement);
    fitAddon.fit();
    

    function handleResize() {
      fitAddon.fit();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      return window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id={id}></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: try `const fitAddon = new FitAddon();` instead of `fitAddon = new FitAddon();` .... does your code work? then it doesn't need to be "global"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't.

As long as the listener exists:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

the callback will not be garbage collected. Since the callback references `fitAddon`, `fitAddon` will not be garbage collected either, no matter where it's declared. So, feel free to declare it inside the effect callback.

```
const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
// ...
```